Looking for a tutorial that creates a basic android app that uses either AWS AIM or google AIM to authenticate
I am trying to learn how to create an android app. My initial Hello world goal is to have an app that uses AWS AIM or google AIM to authenticate. So login page and logged in page.
The difficulty I am having is trying to line up tutorials/articles with the version of the android IDE and default Android/Kotlin app created by the IDE
I first tried
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-android-app-amplify/module-one
But this tutorial is out of date compared to what is created by the Android IDE.
for example the amazon tutorial does not use
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}

Maybe I am approaching this incorrectly. Should I not use the default project creator?
Can anyone suggest a recent tutorial or github repo that would get me started
I assume since I am just getting started, I want to learn using the latest project layouts and packages.
Thanks

I would find the github page for AWS Amplify: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android follow any instructions there and check the github project issues for problems.
